# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError

Tags: python-3.x, pip

How to solve this?

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\sklearn\\.libs\\vcomp140.dll'
Check the permissions.
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks like you don't have permissions to write to the directory where `pip` is trying to install the package.

Try:

```
pip install --user {package_name}
```

Where `{package_name}` is the package you're trying to install.